# Linking to custom libraries

Tags: libraries

I've created a few .cpp and .h files to split my project into smaller parts. The problem is I don't know how to link to them. I've attempted to do so by adding their locations to the directory under Property Pages->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories and also the linker: Property Pages->C/C++->General->Additional Library Directories.

The compiler (MS visual studio 2010 express) however is not finding my files. It gives me an LNK2019 error. I know this is an issue with the linker but I'm not sure how to fix it. Must I add the filenames in the input section of the linker?

Comment: I don't remember the exact options, but in addition to the "Additional Library Directories" you need to specify the libraries themselves. The linker will not read all the files in that directory, it will just search there the library to tell it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you simply need to add all the source files to the project and let the build process do the rest.

It doesn't sound as though you've created any static libraries and so the additional library dependencies settings are not relevant.